# Грань между языком и диалектом

Tags: лингвистика

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где проходит грань между языком и диалектом?
Если взять некоторые диалекты русского языка, то там окажется не так уж много привычных нам слов. Но, тем не менее, мы считает это именно диалектом русского языка. Или другой пример: житель Центральной Украины с большим трудом поймет представителя Западной Украины. Но опять таки это будет именно диалект, а не язык.
Если говорить о территориальном расположении народов, то ведь и внутри страны есть и языки, и диалекты. Так где грань между этими понятиями?

Answer (score 2):

А
 нет четкой грани. Что считать языком, а что диалектом решение скорее 
политическое, чем лингвистическое. Условно можно сказать, что если народ
 ощущает себя единым этносом, но говорит в разных местностях по разному,
 то мы имеем дело с диалектами. Как примеры такой трактовки можем видеть
 значительно отличающиеся друг от друга диалекты немецкого и 
индонезийского языков. Если же народы не считают себя едиными, то даже 
при минимальных отличиях языки объявляются разными. Ярким 
примером такого раздела могут служить сербский и хорватский языки, 
которые по сути отличаются лишь письменностью, но из-за политических 
разногласий эту идентичность предпочитают игнорировать. Исключением из 
этого обобщения будут языки метрополий в бывших колониях.